# When creating a loading bar using printf and \r in c, how does one keep the "moving" code contained

Tags: c, printf

I'm creating a loading bar..and I almost have it but when the "=" sings add to themselves the end of my loading bar moves down the line as well. I want to stop this so instead of

- `progress: |==== | 3%`
- `progress: |============ |3%`

I want

- `progress |== ............... | 3%`
- `progress |=========  .| 3%`

It's hard to see because of the formatting, but I don't want the second "|" line to move with the equal signs.

Here's my code; I think needs a little tweaking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: progress n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    //printf("Enter a percentage: ");
    //scanf("%d", &n);
    //progress: |==================                                |  37%
    //int percentage = 37; 

    char display[70];
    char equals[69];
    char disp[20];

    for (int i = 0; i <=10* n; i++)
    {
        strcpy(display, "progress: |");
        strcat(equals, "=");
        strcpy(disp, "       |");

        char number[10];
        char space[10];

        sprintf(number, "  %d%%", i);
        sprintf(space, "%s", equals);

        strcat(display, space);
        strcat(display, disp);
        strcat(display, number);

        fprintf(stderr, "\r%s %d  \r%s",equals, i, display);
        usleep(1000000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please make your question clearer? The "instead of" and "I want" output is not properly formatted and they look mostly the same anyway (except for the colons).

Comment: It's my first questions ever, they sounded reasonable to me but I'll read more closely next time.

Also I'm trying to fix the question...I didn't realize it wouldn't read spaces. I think it's slightly more clear now.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear what the key difference between the two outputs is. And we can't run the code ourselves since it is incomplete. That's why it is a requirement for all code related questions to provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need to be able to copy your code without any changes and be able to compile and run it.

Comment: I'm trying the best I can. It's harder to format this question than my code. I put the completed code in there although I had to take out a few symbols in order to get them it in there. hope it's clearer

Comment: The key difference is in the first one the equal signs push the end of the loading bar. In the second one the end of the loading bar stays stationary allowing the equal signs arrive to it.

Comment: You can try using backspace characters `\b` and `fflush`.  It's highly terminal dependent though.

Comment: Are the dots part of your desired output?

Comment: Try `sprintf(space, "%-20s", equals);`. That is, add "-20" into that format string. It doesn't do exactly what you want but if you play with that it may give you want you want. Basically what that does is to make the inside "equals" area a fixed width of 20 and left aligned. Obviously you would not actually use 20 in your final code but some calculated width.

Comment: @jonathanleffler No they are not, that's just how I could get the spacing right without reading the html manual.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you! That puts me on the right path! Much appreciated...and thanks for the feedback on my formating.

Comment: *without reading the html manual* this is where you should start

Comment: No problems. I should clarify that what is suggested is called a width specifier. It's not actually a "fixed" width as I wrote previously but a "minimum" width. The string can be longer than that width. That is important for you because the line of equals can grow past the end (20 in the example) if you don't restrict it in some other way.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I was looking at that as part of it but couldn't get there. But I appreciate the help. I've already played with it and it works perfectly.

Comment: All you need to do is print a bunch of spaces between the equals signs and the second bar, so that there's always the same number of characters between the two bars...

Comment: Did you consider using [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) ?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to implement something like you describe could use the `%.*s` substitution for the `fprintf` statement, consider the following example:

```
const int n = 10;

// Initialize two arrays longer than the number of character to output
char s1[n+1] = "##########";
char s2[n+1] = "          ";

for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    // Only output the first i characters of s1
    // And the first (n-i) characters of s2
    fprintf(stderr, "Progress: |%.*s%.*s| %02d\r", i, s1, n-i, s2, i);
    fflush(stderr);  //< Flush the output (just in case)
    usleep(1000000);
}

fprintf(stderr, "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand what you're trying to achieve here. It can be done with fewer buffers and fewer lines of code.

You can have the blank spaces replaced with `.` characters by modifying `char c` in the if-else check.

We `memset()` the buffer so that we don't have to worry about setting the end of our string stored in `buf` to `NULL`.

---

## Code Listing

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_LEN     (1024)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: progress n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    char buf[BUF_LEN];
    const int iLimit = 10*n;

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= iLimit; i++)
    {
        memset(buf, 0, BUF_LEN);
        for ( j = 0; j < iLimit; j++ )
        {
            char c;
            if ( j <= i )
            {
                c = '=';
            }
            else
            {
                c = ' ';
            }
            buf[j] = c;
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "Progress: | %s | %%%03d", buf, (int)(i*100/iLimit));
        fflush(stdout);

        // Reset the cursor position
        fprintf(stdout, "\r");
        usleep(100000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job, I think:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char spaces[80];
    char equals[80];

    /* Assume an 80-column screen */
    /* The 'progress: |' is 11 characters */
    /* There should be space for '| 100%' after it */
    /* So that's 17 characters overhead. */
    /* We'll use 60 characters for the bar (not using 3) */

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        /* Length of bar = (i * 60) / 100 */
        int barlen = (i * 60) / 100;
        int spclen = 60 - barlen;
        memset(equals, '=', barlen);
        equals[barlen] = '\0';
        memset(spaces, ' ', spclen);
        spaces[spclen] = '\0';
        fprintf(stderr, "\rprogress: |%s%s| %3d%%", equals, spaces, i);
        usleep(200000);
    }
    usleep(2000000);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The loop counts from 0 to 100 for percentage complete.  It formats a line of `=` signs of the correct length, and a line of spaces for the correct length.  There are definitely other ways to do it than brute-forcing it with `memset()`, but that works.  (Note that `printf()` does not, as standard, have a repeat operator.)  It then formats the line.  The sample output was generated with a modified version of the code (including a `\n` at the end of the format string).

```
progress: |                                                            |   0%
progress: |                                                            |   1%
progress: |=                                                           |   2%
progress: |=                                                           |   3%
progress: |==                                                          |   4%
progress: |===                                                         |   5%
…
progress: |============================                                |  47%
progress: |============================                                |  48%
progress: |=============================                               |  49%
progress: |==============================                              |  50%
progress: |==============================                              |  51%
progress: |===============================                             |  52%
…
progress: |=========================================================   |  96%
progress: |==========================================================  |  97%
progress: |==========================================================  |  98%
progress: |=========================================================== |  99%
progress: |============================================================| 100%
```

Incremental building of the line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char spaces[80];

    /* Assume an 80-column screen */
    /* The 'progress: |' is 11 characters */
    /* There should be space for '| 100%' after it */
    /* So that's 17 characters overhead. */
    /* We'll use 60 characters for the bar (not using 3) */

    memset(spaces, ' ', 60);
    spaces[60] = '\0';

    int oldbar = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        /* Length of bar = (i * 60) / 100 */
        int newbar = (i * 60) / 100;
        if (oldbar != newbar)
            spaces[newbar-1] = '=';
        fprintf(stderr, "\rprogress: |%s| %3d%%", spaces, i);
        oldbar = newbar;
        usleep(200000);
    }
    usleep(2000000);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

It produces the same output.  OTOH, efficiency concerns when the main loop is waiting 200 ms per iteration are mainly a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

first, the code needs to determine how many columns will be taken by the completed progress bar.

Then the number of iterations through the loop needs to be determined (usually the same as the max number of `=` characters)

then print the whole progress bar, with all spaces.

then in the loop prints the current number of `=` characters + prints the current number of 'unfilled' spaces.